# Team viewer install dependency problem

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit. I tried to install teamviewer with deb file.

```
$sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_12.0.76279_i386.deb 

Selecting previously unselected package teamviewer:i386.
(Reading database ... 175695 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack teamviewer_12.0.76279_i386.deb ...
Unpacking teamviewer:i386 (12.0.76279) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of teamviewer:i386:
 teamviewer:i386 depends on libdbus-1-3.
 teamviewer:i386 depends on libexpat1.
 teamviewer:i386 depends on libfontconfig1.
 teamviewer:i386 depends on libsm6.

 dpkg: error processing package teamviewer:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
 Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
 Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1) ...
 Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
 Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
 Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  teamviewer:i386
```

Then I checked and confirmed 64 bit versions of these packets installed.

```
$dpkg-query -s libexpat1:amd64
Status: install ok installed

$dpkg-query -s libsm6:amd64
Status: install ok installed

$dpkg-query -s libdbus-1-3:amd64
Status: install ok installed

$dpkg-query -s libfontconfig1:amd64
Status: install ok installed
```

I also checked if multi-arch support installed

```
$dpkg -l | grep multiarch
ii  multiarch-support    2.23-0ubuntu3    amd64
```

I also tried

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Remove it from the system then try again with `sudo apt update; sudo gdebi -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes teamviewer_12.0.76279_i386.deb` . [edit] the question and add that debug log.

Comment: Problem is solved after restoring sources.list as explained in the link below https://askubuntu.com/questions/769925/please-help-sudo-apt-get-update-error-ubuntu-16-04-lts-version

Answer (score 4):

**The [official install instructions for Team Viewer](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Installation-of-TeamViewer-on-a-Ubuntu-system/ta-p/45) using GUI are**:

To install TeamViewer on your Ubuntu system, follow these steps:

1. Download the TeamViewer full version under http://www.teamviewer.com/download.
2. Open the teamviewer_linux.deb file with a double click.
       The TeamViewer installation package will open in the Ubuntu Software Center.
3. Click on the Install button.
       The Authenticate dialog box will open.
4. Enter the administrative password.
   Click on the Authenticate button.
       TeamViewer will be installed.
       The status within the Ubuntu Software Center changes to Installed.
   TeamViewer is installed on your Ubuntu system.

**[Install using a command line](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-do-I-install-TeamViewer-on-my-Linux-distribution/ta-p/4351):**

For installing TeamViewer, we recommend using the graphical installer, as described above.

- If you prefer to use the command line, or if there is no graphical installer available, you can use one of these commands as an administrator:

  ```
  apt install teamviewer_12.0.xxxxx_i386.deb
  ```
- *Older systems (Ubuntu 14.04, Debian 7 and below)*

  Run this command:

  ```
  dpkg -i teamviewer_12.0.xxxxx_i386.deb
  ```
- In case dpkg indicates missing dependencies, complete the installation by executing the following command:

  ```
  apt-get install -f
  ```

**[GDebi](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gdebi/) - General tool to install deb packages with their dependencies**

You can also install `.deb` file using gdebi.

- Install gdebi:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
  ```
- Install .deb packages with gdebi:

  ```
  sudo gdebi filename.deb
  ```

Comment: @mehmetrizaoz - did you install it using the `Ubuntu Software Center` as recommended by the Team Viewer official instructions?

Comment: i did it first but  trying to install with         sudo apt install teamviewer_12.0.76279_i386.deb gave me             E: Unable to locate package teamviewer_12.0.76279_i386.deb             E: Unable to locate package teamviewer_12.0.76279_i386.deb             E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'teamviewer_12.0.76279_i386.deb             error message then i tried to install with dpkg.

Comment: and installing from software center produced an unmoving progress bar.

Comment: @mehmetrizaoz - I've added another option for install using gdebi. Please note, I've tested the GUI install (using Ubuntu software center) and it was installed in a one-click on a Ubuntu 16.04 without any problems.

Comment: it says            Cannot install 'libdbus-1-3:i386'    in the end

Comment: Please check if  [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/498131/544264) or [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/734934/544264) The problem of installing libdus

Comment: cant install for i386 again, it says                 libdbus-1-3:i386 : Depends: libsystemd0:i386 but it is not going to be installed